# Integrating address verification based on pincode and vice versa for Indian Pincode

Tags: addressbook, postal-code

We are trying to build address validator and was wondering if storing the data can become obsolete or will be a maintenance task.

Adding a API would rather be long lasting. There are not many resources which are kept updated

I have checked below Links.All of them are out dated and do not have latest data.

- http://www.postalpincode.in/Api-Details
- https://pincode.net.in/194101

Also there is not much on documentation part -

- https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/api#/Resource/get_resource_6176ee09_3d56_4a3b_8115_21841576b2f6
  Anyone who is already doing it in better way then storing data to app local db.

I tried below link and the data I got from this link is outdated.

- https://data.gov.in/catalog/pincode-search?filters%5Bfield_catalog_reference%5D=90054&format=json&offset=0&limit=6&sort%5Bcreated%5D=desc
- https://data.gov.in/node/85839/download

Comment: You can try www.indianpincodes.co.in. We use it for our projects.

Answer (score 5):

Indian Post would be the most reliable source of information, the other site you referred () gets data from Indian Post -

> https://api.postalpincode.in/

It works fine for most of the pin-codes however the recent split of J&K doesn't seem to be updated yet.

- https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/400005 (Mumbai)
- https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/110006 (Delhi)
- https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/194101 (Leh)

The government sites' data usually take much longer to get updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Manish, I have already explored this api as mentioned in question itself. Government sites do delay, but its been almost a year now, they have not updated the data.I mailed to them as well and its been 2 weeks, no reply yet.

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya : any update on this ?. I'm too stuck here,,,did u get any reliable API for this?>

Comment: @Balwinder No update, no reply from Post as well. We are running with static data, for any exception we handle adhoc.

Comment: You can use https://www.indianpincodes.co.in/

Answer (score -2):

You can find the updated Indian postal or pin code information from "India Pincode with Latitude and Longitude" API.

1. This API provides approximately 1.6L pin codes all over India.
2. Can check the distance between two pin code.
3. Can find the distance between areas by latitude and longitude.
4. Can get the details of pin codes.
5. Nearby areas pin code.
6. Pin code by state.

Find the API: https://rapidapi.com/vigowebs/api/india-pincode-with-latitude-and-longitude